# Is there a JavaScript InDesign function to get ID value

Tags: javascript, photoshop, extendscript

I used the command to export the hard drive ID to drive C:

```
var command="wmic diskdrive get SerialNumber > C:/idhdd.txt"; 
app.system("cmd.exe /c\""+command+"" );
```

I get the text file

```
SerialNumber      
2012062914345300
```

Is there a JavaScript statement to remove SerialNumber, I just want to get the ID in the text file and save it to the hard drive C.

Comment: I assume this is node.js and not just javascript. correct? Does it have to be javascript? This would be much easier via shell scripting. What OS are you using?

Comment: I am using windows, it is javascript

Comment: That's not a JS command, that's a Windows command you can though JS.

Answer (score 0):

Here's ready-to-use `getDriveIDs()` function that should work in any Adobe app and will return array of HDD ID strings for you. I hope this can be easily generalized for other scenarios with Windows scripting inside Adobe scripting ;-)

```js
//----------------------------------------------------------------------//

// Detects IDs (serial numbers) of connected drives and returns them as array of strings.

var getDriveIDs = function() {
    var idFile = File(Folder.temp + '/saved_hdd_serials.txt');
    var scriptFile = File(Folder.temp + '/dump_hdd_serials.bat');
    var scriptContent = 'wmic diskdrive get SerialNumber > ' + idFile.fsName + '\n';
    var ids = []
    withTempFile(scriptFile, scriptContent, function() {
        scriptFile.execute();
        $.writeln(idFile.length == 0); // wait for asynchronous script execution to finish
            $.sleep(1);
        withTempFile(idFile, undefined, function(file, lines) {
            ids = lines.slice(1);
        });
    });
    return ids;
};

//----------------------------------------------------------------------//
// utilities

var withTempFile = function(file, content, callback) {
    if (undefined == content) { // read temp file
        file.open('r');
        content = [];
        while (!file.eof)
            content.push(file.readln());
    } else { // write temp file
        file.open('w');
        file.write(content);
        content = undefined;
    }
    file.close();
    callback(file, content);
    file.remove();
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------//
// main: demo

var ids = getDriveIDs();
alert('Drive IDs:\n\t' + ids.join('\n\t'));
```